# How to query Contacts that have both a phone number and name?

Tags: android, cursor, android-contentprovider, android-contacts

I have following code in pre-Android2.0 API:

```
    String[] PROJECTION = new String[] { Contacts.People._ID, Contacts.PeopleColumns.NAME, Contacts.Phones.NUMBER };
    Cursor c = mActivity.managedQuery(Contacts.People.CONTENT_URI, PROJECTION, null, null, Contacts.People.DEFAULT_SORT_ORDER);
```

What kind of selection should I do to retrieve contacts that have both name and phone number?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Android 1.6 and older:

```
String[] PROJECTION=new String[] {  Contacts.Phones._ID,
                                    Contacts.Phones.NAME,
                                    Contacts.Phones.NUMBER
                                    };
Cursor c=a.managedQuery(Contacts.Phones.CONTENT_URI, PROJECTION, null, null, null);
```

In Android 2.0 and newer:

```
String[] PROJECTION=new String[] {  Contacts._ID,
                                    Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME,
                                    Phone.NUMBER
                                    };
Cursor c=a.managedQuery(Phone.CONTENT_URI, PROJECTION, null, null, null);
```

[Here is a sample project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-advandroid/tree/master/Contacts/Spinners/) demonstrating their use, including detecting and using the proper API based on device OS level.

Comment: Ok, but how to get People._ID in such query? (That ID would be used for contact photo retrieval)

Comment: @pixel: Well, I'm a bit sloppy in this code (note to self: clean this up). The `Contacts._ID` in the 2nd example is the contact's _ID, which would be what you would need for near-term queries. The equivalent for the older would be `Contacts.Phones.PERSON_ID`, I believe.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't notice this constant. One more thing - when I have contacts with two phone numbers I get two rows with same name and different phones. Do you have any clue how to get one contact with two numbers?

Comment: @pixel: That's not possible, sorry. You will have to merge them yourself.

Comment: @CommonsWare With this technique I am unable to see any synchronised contacts (only the ones manually entered). How could I include them in the result? Also, how do I sort the numbers by name in ascending? Referring to your book but unable to get this. Please help :-)

Comment: @Angad: "With this technique I am unable to see any synchronised contacts" -- you need to use `ContactsContract`. This question is from late 2010, back when the `Contacts` provider was far more relevant. Also, `managedQuery()` is now deprecated. "Also, how do I sort the numbers by name in ascending?" -- you would need to use the appropriate order-by clause in your `query()` (on `ContentResolver`) or `CursorLoader`. "Referring to your book but unable to get this" -- yeah, wow, that chapter needs a serious update. I'll get on that for the next book release.

Comment: @CommonsWare could be great if you could link me to an updated sample/share constant names that I could look-up. Needed to get this running ASAP and the official docs are scattered as hell :(

Comment: @Angad: Sorry, but I don't have anything handy.

Comment: @CommonsWare just got it working, thanks for the initial detailed comment! Gave me pointers as to what to Google.